# Change image when clicked via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm building a website for home automation, I'm trying to get the image to change when I click it but what happens is it disappears into nothing and doesn't change back! I've tried multiple online scripts but same result.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Raspberry Pi Home Automation</title>
<link href="css/singlePageTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  function changeImage() {

      if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "C:\Users\Nour\Desktop\Raspberry Pi Website\images\light_is_on.png")
      {
          document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "C:\Users\Nour\Desktop\Raspberry Pi Website\images\light_is_off.png";
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "C:\Users\Nour\Desktop\Raspberry Pi Website\images\light_is_on.png";
      }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> <img src="C:\Users\Nour\Desktop\Raspberry Pi Website\images\light_is_on.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you keep the images in the project folder itself and give it a try.
There seems to be the file path issue, soooo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is happening for you but your script seems to be working fine as you can see below.

Are you sure the image paths/file names are correct? If the second image doesn't exist it will just be an empty tag with no src image and therefore have no width or height for you to click it again to change it back.

Check the console also and let us know if there are any errors there.

```js
function changeImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff"){
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/ff0000";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000ff" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()">
```

Comment: That is a great snippet, I also think that the image paths are not valid.

Comment: Fixed it! I've uploaded the images to imgur and voila!

Comment: Great, not sure if this might have caused it but I don't like having spaces in my image path